# How do i make a pop up in a .bat script that ask me if i want to restart the computer?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I make a pop up in a .bat script that asks me if I want to restart the computer?

I have made a .bat script and I want that after the process is done shows a popup asking if the user want to restart, with two buttons ("*yes*" and "*no*").

Comment: You can't as CMD by itself does not have any windowed UI (`prompt` can ask in console, but it does not look like what you are interested in...)... Side note please avoid excessive usage of bold/thank you notes in the posts.

Comment: You're going to want vbscript for this; batch can't do things with GUIs. (Also, the PowerShell enthusiasts will tell you to use PowerShell, but I personally think vbscript would be easier.)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mention, you can't create a popup window in pure batch (unless you just want to open another command prompt), but you can prompt for a Yes/No question easily using the CHOICE command.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732504.aspx

To create a popup, you would need to write a script in another language that returns an errorlevel you can check, call the script from your batch command, and then check the errorlevel to determine what the user selected.